# Cannot call JQuery functions

Tags: jquery

Help!!! I can't get this Jquery code to run, the functions don't call, I've looked for numerous solutions and tried various different ways of solving this problem but yet I'm still stuck! Any suggestions would be much appreciated thanks! P.S Im certain indentation is correct, it appears weird in the snippet below and incorrect 0.o

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#explore-drop-menu").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).show_drop_menu("#explore-drop-menu");
 });

 $("#explore-drop-menu").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).hide_drop_menu("#explore-drop-menu");
 });

 $.fn.show_drop_menu = function(drop_menu_id){
     $(drop_menu_id).css({
      "transition":"1s",`enter code here`
      "height":"300px",
      "opacity":"1"
     });

     $("#nav").css({
      "transition":"1s",
      "background-color":"#F0F0F0"
     });

     $("body").css({
      "transition":"1s",
      "background-color":"#404040"
     });
 });

 $.fn.hide_drop_menu = function(drop_menu_id){
     $(drop_menu_id).css({
      "transition":"1s",
      "height":"0px",
      "opacity":"0"
     });

     $("#nav").css({
      "transition":"1s",
      "background-color":"#212121"
     });

     $("body").css({
      "transition":"1s",
      "background-color":"white"
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: what is `drop_menu_id`? you have extra `});` in there. What does your browser's console say? *hint* Web inspector is your friend.

Comment: When you say "the functions don't call," do you mean they aren't being executed? Which functions are you talking about? Or to ask it another way, how far is it getting? Are the anonymous functions you've bound as event handlers even getting called? If not, since these are event handlers bound to DOM elements, we'll need to see the markup to have any idea on why it's not working. If those functions are executed, does it then execute the corresponding show/hide_drop_menu? If so, how far does it get into those functions before failing?

Comment: The website loads, when I hover over the links it does not execute this Jquery script at all, and drop_menu_id is the id for a div, there are four links each with a unique div, the drop_menu_id is a string variable that changes depending on which link the user is hovering above.

Comment: The console has no errors, the script just doesn't run, I've validated the syntax and tried multiple methods still not working

Comment: FIXED IT! WOW I MADE A DUMB MISTAKE XD accidentally was using # instead of . for explore-drop-menu, issues resolved thanks!